# use data outside a foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I write a form with many stuff inside and then use foreach to take the information.
So far my foreach works well but if I use the information outside the foreach I get some strange data.

Here is my code with only the foreach and data extraction:

```
foreach ($_POST['number3'] as $id1 => $array) {
        foreach ($array as $id2 => $alpha) {
                 foreach ($alpha as $id3 => $gama) {
                         $_SESSION['number3'][$id1][$id2][$id3] = $gama;
                        echo 'The value of $_SESSION["'.$id1.'"]["'.$id2.'"] ["'.$id3.'"] is '."'".$gama."'".' <br />';
                     }
                }
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION["number"]; $i++) {
        echo "Numero ";
        echo $i;
        echo "<br />";
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $_SESSION["number2_{$i}"]; $j++) {           
            echo "Letter ";
            echo $j;
            echo ": ";
            for ($id = 0; $id <= $_SESSION["id"]; $id++) {          
                echo "value: ";
                echo " ";
                echo $_SESSION['number3'][$i][$j][$id]; 
            }   
            echo "<br />";              
        }           
    }
```

With the echo in my foreach I will get data like this:

```
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["1"] ["0"] is '13:01' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["1"] ["1"] is '01:01' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["1"] ["2"] is '1' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["2"] ["0"] is '14:02' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["2"] ["1"] is '02:02' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["2"] ["2"] is '2' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["3"] ["0"] is '15:03' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["3"] ["1"] is '03:03' 
The value of $_SESSION["1"]["3"] ["2"] is '3'
```

This is what I want so no problem here. But when I do the for loop I get this:

```
Numero 1
Letter 1: value: 13:01 value: 01:01 value: 1
Letter 2: value: 1 value: 0 value: 2
Letter 3: value: 15:03 value: 03:03 value: 3
```

For the letter 2, the data are wrong for the 2 first value and I don't understand why since after everything is normal.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: your accessing a completely different set of keys in your for loop than you did in your  foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the value assignment of $_SESSION['number3'][$id1][$id2][$id3]. You can try "var_dump" or "var_export" in your code to fond out the real data structure of $_SESSION, see whether assign wrong keys or somewhere changed this value.

Just from the code above, I could not find anything wrong, but I'm sure this is not a difficult problem, try run & var_dump & debug it.

Comment: I use var_dump and get this result:
string(5) "01:01" string(5) "13:01" string(1) "1" 
string(1) "0" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" 
string(5) "03:03" string(5) "15:03" string(1) "3"
I'm not really sure how to debug it

Comment: From the result above it seems the data sotred int $_SESSION is not correct, to debug, you can follow the data manipulation process and try to find out whether the data stored correctly, whether somewhere changed it, or using wrong keys to read it.